# Proper html markup of table tags?

Tags: html, html-table

Kind of a silly question, but I've been seeing things such as tbody and thead/tfoot tags in other peoples tables.

Are these required even if they're empty for good markup? Or can I just leave them out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table sections (thead/tbody/tfoot) are optional. The table caption (caption) and column definitons (col/colgroup) are also optional.

In HTML (but not XHTML) the closing tag for rows and cells are also optional, so you could write a table as:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1
    <th>2
  <tr>
    <td>3
    <td>4
  <tr>
    <td>5
    <td>6
</table>
```

It's however recommended that you close the tags to get better structure in the code. It also makes it a lot easier if you decide to change to XHTML.

Comment: Always close tags... seriously

Comment: @Coulton: Yes, as I explained in the answer, it's recommended, but not required by the HTML standard.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't required, but they let you do some more advanced things with headers and footers:
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmladvanced/tables/

Answer (score 2):

Those tags are not required and a page would validate even without them.

Answer (score 0):

if you really need tables, you should use them. If you use tables only for design purposes you should switch to css-markup.

A simple correct table example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>User1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>User2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should never use tables for design purposes :) That's what div- and p-tags were invented for.

Comment: well im trying to spread out my navigation links evenly(Gallery, Portfolio, Contact, etc)- i figured a table would be easiest way to get the aesthetics i wanted

Comment: Tables are for showing data which HAVE a table form. Design purposes should NEVER NEVER NEVER be designed with tables, CSS can do all you want to and much more.

Comment: @Gazow you should use an unordered list for navigation rather than a table, here's some basics on the code you would need for that purpose: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is proper markup.
Though they are optional
You can read further on the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp) page.

Answer (score 0):

The `<tbody>` tag is only partially supported in all major browsers.
Tables may have multiple bodies, but when it only has one single body, the HTML tbody tag may be safely omitted.